# what's the class and field order of loading in java?

Tags: java, class

the java source code like:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.println(X.Y.Z);
    }   
}


class X { 
    static class Y{
       static String Z = "balck";
    }   

    static C Y  = new C();
}

class C{
    String Z = "white";
}
```

why the result is:`white`?

Comment: Often taking the initial code and refactoring it can show the solution; this is all down to class Y and variable Y both existing, if you refactored the line System.out.println(X.Y.Z); with X-->A Y-->B and Z-->C the Y that is actually being used reveals itself

Comment: consider using an IDE, that warns you about fouls, like using Uppercase letter for variables.

Comment: Nothing to do with loading, and everything to do with scoping and hiding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please see the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1)

> 6.4.2. Obscuring
>
> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package. In these situations, the rules of §6.5 specify that a variable will be chosen in preference to a type, and that a type will be chosen in preference to a package. Thus, it is may sometimes be impossible to refer to a visible type or package declaration via its simple name. We say that such a declaration is obscured.

Under section [6.5.2. Reclassification of Contextually Ambiguous Names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.2):

> If the name to the left of the "." is reclassified as a TypeName, then:
>
> 1. If the Identifier is the name of a method or field of the type denoted by TypeName, this AmbiguousName is reclassified as an ExpressionName.
> 2. Otherwise, if the Identifier is the name of a member type of the type denoted by TypeName, this AmbiguousName is reclassified as a TypeName.
> 3. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

Your inner class and static variable are named the same. It doesn't have to do anything with the order of class loading, `X.Y` is interpreted as an acces to the variable, not the inner class.

Answer (score 4):

The result is `white`, **because your naming convention is extremely bad**.

Regardless of the technical reasons other people will/have given you, the sole reason for even thinking about the problem is that you named your variables in such a manner, that you yourself and all other people will have trouble reading and understanding. And the only thing that will have no trouble is the compiler, which is defined strictly enough to know what to do.

Comment: I'm desperately hoping this is a puzzle, not an actual way real code was written

Answer (score 2):

This is a trick question. The class `Y` is never used, `static C Y  = new C();` is an instance of class C named Y and has nothing to do with the class `Y`